# WindowsServer 2012, Multiple users and multiple IPs

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

We have server with 4 additional IPs. we have 4 users that use RDP to connect to the server. I'd like each user have separate IP for connecting and this IP will be showing when he'll use internet (browser etc.) on the server.

Is it possible?

Comment: It should be. Have you tried?

Comment: Remember that, without Terminal Server Licenses, only two users can be logged on at the same time...

Comment: @montonero, could you tell what I need to do step by step or just provide a link where I can find instructions. Thank you in advance

Comment: @Влад It would be nice if you share with us what have you tried so far and which issue(s) you have. Have you just tried to connect to these IPs? How they are configured? Your question is pretty broad.

Comment: I didn't try anything yet, I don't know from what to start. Just I asked my provider aobut this and he told that it's not possible, but I'm sure that it does, I know that some guys did that

Comment: Let me rephrase montonero's question: what do you want to know - if you can access RDP through different IPs or if the access is logged?

Comment: @Tobias, I'd like to know can I get access RDP through different IPs? and also is it possible for each user to have external IPs (it must be showing as the same as connected to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give you multiple answers, I hope it is what you need:

- **Can I access a Windows Server via RDP through all the available IP adresses?**

Yes. You can disable the connection to RDP for specific IPs in the Windows firewall, but if you enable RDP it should work by default with all IPs that are configured on the server.

- **Can different users access the server via RDP from different source IP addresses?**

Same as above: yes, but you can block different IPs or even IP ranges for RDP access in the Windows firewall. Like above, if you enable RDP, it should work by default.

- **Can the RDP users use external IP addresses?**

Of course. But if by external IP adresses you mean that they access the server from the internet: it is possible to configure your internet gateway to do so (open port 3389 from external addresses to the RDP server, and use port forwarding to the server if it is using non-routable IP addresses), but IMHO it is absolutly not recommended. Windows Server should not be put on the internet without additional security gateways in-between. But if all your users are sitting behind the same gateway and are using public IP addresses (had that configuration in my last job...), there is absolutly no problem with accessing the servers via RDP.

- **Can I see who acessed the server by using a specific server IP address?**

I do not know a way doing this only with the windows server. If you have a firewall or any routing device with logging capabilities between your clients and the server, you could log the traffic between these IPs. But as far as I know the Windows log only shows you the originating IP address of the client, not the IP of the server. One way to be able to see this on the server is to run a packet tracer like Wireshark in the background with a capture filter only logging RDP related events.

Answer (score -1):

There is one part of the question that is not answered yet:

> [...] and this IP will be showing when he'll use internet (browser etc.) on the server.

I don't see any way to do that. Generally the outgoing IP address is determined by the routing table of the server, and the routing table is per machine, not per user.

There are programs that can allow to specify an interface for outgoing connections (for example `curl --interface`), but I'm not aware of any Windows application that allows that, and while I'm sure there exist some esoteric tools that do it, it would have to be configured per user AND per application.

Also, as far as I know (I may be wrong here, I'm not that deep an expert in Windows Server) there is no way to restrict the login of a user to a specific (local to the server) IP address. All users would be able to connect to all IP addresses on the server.

So, while it is no problem to have your users connect to the server through all IP addresses, I don't see a viable solution to restrict a user to their own IP address, incoming or outgoing.

Comment: It would be nice if the downvoter would explain how he thinks this is possible. I'm always happy to learn something new.